# Android - Mysterious Black Box Appearing

Tags: android, layout

My android app is going well, save for the appearance of a strange black box that doesn't seem to have any cause.

Here's the XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

          <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
      </ScrollView>
  </FrameLayout>

  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And here's my code to handle the situation in which the black box appears:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //int i = position;
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.scroll_layout, fragment).commit();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String area = sharedPreferences.getString("area", "Home");

    //String[] menuSelection = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_menu_array);
    ArrayList<String> menuArray = getMenuArray(area);
    String[] menuSelection = menuArray.toArray(new String[menuArray.size()]);

    String loc = menuSelection[position];
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("area", loc);
    editor.commit();
    if (loc.equals("Area1") || loc.equals("Area2") || loc.equals("Area3") || loc.equals("Vendors") || loc.equals("Announcements")){


        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("section", loc);
        editor.commit(); 


    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mForumTitles[position]);
    ArrayList<String> arList = getMenuArray(loc);

    String[] newArr = arList.toArray(new String[arList.size()]);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, newArr));
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    setMainView(loc, newArr[0]);

    }else{

        loc = sharedPreferences.getString("section", "Speakers");

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        //setTitle(mForumTitles[position]);
        ArrayList<String> arList = getMenuArray(loc);

        String[] newArr = arList.toArray(new String[arList.size()]);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, newArr));
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        setMainView(loc, newArr[position]);

    }
}
private void setMainView(String section, String selection){
    mTableView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scroll_layout);
    mTableView.removeAllViews();
    ArrayList<String> info = getInfoArray(section, selection);
    String[] instructions = info.get(0).split("\\|"); 
    String[] values = info.get(1).split("\\|");
    for(int i=0; i < instructions.length; i++){
            if (instructions[i].equals("@image")){
                //TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);

                ImageView newImage = new ImageView(this);

                newImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
                //newRow.addView(newImage);
                 mTableView.addView(newImage);
            }else{
                //TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
                TextView newText = new TextView(this);
                newText.setText(instructions[i] + ": " + values[i]);
                newText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                newText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
                //newRow.addView(newText);
                 mTableView.addView(newText);
            }

    }
    //TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
    TextView newText = new TextView(this);
    //newText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    newText.setText(info.get(2));
    newText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20);
    newText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);


    //newRow.addView(newText);
    mTableView.setPadding(60, 20, 60, 0);
    mTableView.addView(newText);
}



private ArrayList<String> getInfoArray(String section, String selection){
    ArrayList<String> fileArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        String str = "http://www.mysite./area/" + section + "/" + selection + ".txt";

        //URL url = new URL(");
        str = str.replace(" ", "%20");
        str = str.replace(",", "%2C");
        URL url = new URL(str);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
             fileArray.add(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return fileArray;

}

private ArrayList<String> getMenuArray(String section){

    ArrayList<String> fileArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        String str = "http://www.mysite.com/area/" + section + ".txt";

        //URL url = new URL(");
        str = str.replace(" ", "%20");
        str = str.replace(",", "%2C");
        URL url = new URL(str);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        str = str + "";
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
             fileArray.add(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

And here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Cookiki Done. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resolved itself. I created a new project, copied all the code over, and the problem vanished. Oh well. Thanks to anyone who tried to solve it.